# Getting rectangle from exporting image polygon from Google Earth Engine

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to export a polygon from an image with Google Earth Engine
but the result is an image with rectangle holes in it:

[image]

My code:

```
task_config = {
        'region': polygon,
        'crs': 'EPSG:32636',
        'crsTransform':[20, 0, 600000, 0, -20, 3400020],
        'fileFormat': 'GeoTIFF',
        'fileNamePrefix': fileNamePrefix ,
        'folder': destination,
        'image': cd,
        'description': 'imageToDriveExample_test',
    }
out = batch.Export.image.toDrive(**task_config)
process = batch.Task.start(out)
print(fileNamePrefix, 'is in {} folder'.format(destination))
```

There is no problems with my polygon

Comment: Can you post a complete link?

Comment: I'm working on Jupyter notebook